# Can we say "Her eyes stick to her phone like glue" to mean "Her eyes are glued to her phone"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

Normally we say "**Her dog sticks to her like glue.**" to mean her dog stay very close to her.

And we say "**Her eyes are glued to her phone**" to mean she gives all her attention to her phone and spends to much time on her phone.

Can we say "**Her eyes stick to her phone like glue**" to mean "**Her eyes are glued to her phone**", for example, "**Her eyes stick to her phone like glue that she has no time to talk to her children**"?

Comment: No, I don't think so. "sticks to x like glue" implies physical closeness. It doesn't work the same way as eyes being metaphorically "glued" to something.

Answer (score 1):

As Katy has mentioned, "Sticks to x like glue" implies physical closeness and doesn't quite work in the metaphorical sense.

In this particular example, you could, however, say something along the lines of:

> *She is glued to her phone*

> **She is glued to her phone** so much that she has no time to talk to her children.

> She doesn't have time to talk to her children because **she is always glued to her phone**.